# Time difference with R. When day, month and year absent

Tags: r, date

How to get date difference with R (in term of minutes) when day, month and year were not provided.

For instance minutes betweeen "23:14:01" and "00:02:01".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `difftime`:

```
a <- strptime("23:14:01",format = "%H:%M:%S")
b <- strptime("00:02:01",format = "%H:%M:%S")

difftime(a,b, units = "mins")
# Time difference of 1392 mins

difftime_res_2 <- 1440 - difftime_res # In case the times are from following days

difftime_res_2
# Time difference of 48 mins
```

Comment: But if those times come from following days?

Comment: I added a solution for following days.

Comment: Thanks a lot; via adding a very small ifelse, I have solved my questions with your code.